# Ejecución en Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, ejecutar, logcat

Cuando ejecuto la aplicación en el emulador y en mi dispositivo físico, la aplicación se abre y se cierra al instante, aparece "La aplicación continua fallando"/"La aplicación dejo de funcionar" y pensé que era porque tenia el abstract en el `public class MainActivity`, pero tampoco funciono. En un principio, la aplicación funcionaba bien, tenia mis botones switch y el sharedpreference para guardarlos, pero cuando intente poner un segundo Activity, la aplicación empezó a presentar este problema.

Les dejo mi logcat:

```
Process: xyz.devleen.administradordetareas1, PID: 18701
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{xyz.devleen.administradordetareas1/xyz.devleen.administradordetareas1.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #281 in xyz.devleen.administradordetareas1:layout/main_activity: Binary XML file line #281: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3430)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3594)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2067)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7698)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:952)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #281 in xyz.devleen.administradordetareas1:layout/main_activity: Binary XML file line #281: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Binary XML file line #281: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:830)
        at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:8231)
        at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:8429)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(LinearLayout.java:2023)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:1917)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:89)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at xyz.devleen.administradordetareas1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1310)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3403)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3594)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2067)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7698)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:952)
```

**Y mi main activity:**

```
package xyz.devleen.administradordetareas1;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;


public abstract class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   TextView tvBoton;
   private Switch quim, fil, fis, tri, esp, engl, inf, eti, reli, est, pol, dib, edf, mate;
   private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, sharfil, sharquim, shardfis, shartrig, sharesp, sharemate, sharing, sharinf, shareti, sharrel, sharest, sharpol, sharedf;
   public static final String ex1 = "switch1";
   public static final String ex = "switch";


   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
       dib = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);
       sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("dib", MODE_PRIVATE);
       final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
       dib.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean(ex, false));
       dib.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
           @Override
           public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
               if (isChecked) {
                   editor.putBoolean(ex, true);
               } else {
                   editor.putBoolean(ex, false);
               }
               editor.commit();
           }
       });

       fil = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch24);
       sharfil = getSharedPreferences("fil", MODE_PRIVATE);
       final SharedPreferences.Editor editorr = sharfil.edit();
       fil.setChecked(sharfil.getBoolean(ex, false));
       fil.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
           @Override
           public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean issyChecked) {
               if (issyChecked) {
                   editorr.putBoolean(ex, true);
               } else {
                   editorr.putBoolean(ex, false);
               }
               editorr.commit();
           }
       });
       esp = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch2);
       sharesp = getSharedPreferences("esp", MODE_PRIVATE);
       final SharedPreferences.Editor editoresp = sharesp.edit();
       esp.setChecked(sharesp.getBoolean(ex, false));
       esp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
           @Override
           public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isespChecked) {
               if (isespChecked) {
                   editoresp.putBoolean(ex, true);
               } else {
                   editoresp.putBoolean(ex, false);
               }
               editoresp.commit();
           }
       });

       quim = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch21);
       sharquim = getSharedPreferences("quim", MODE_PRIVATE);
       final SharedPreferences.Editor editorrr = sharquim.edit();
       quim.setChecked(sharquim.getBoolean(ex, false));
       quim.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
           @Override
           public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isssChecked) {
               if (isssChecked) {
                   editorrr.putBoolean(ex, true);
               } else {
                   editorrr.putBoolean(ex, false);
               }
               editorrr.commit();
           }
       });

       fis = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch22);
       shardfis = getSharedPreferences("fis", MODE_PRIVATE);
       final SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = shardfis.edit();
       fis.setChecked(shardfis.getBoolean(ex, false));
       fis.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
           @Override
           public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean iscChecked) {
               if (iscChecked) {
                   editor1.putBoolean(ex, true);
               } else {
                   editor1.putBoolean(ex, false);
               }
               editor1.commit();
           }
       });

       tri = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch6);
       shartrig = getSharedPreferences("tri", MODE_PRIVATE);
       final SharedPreferences.Editor editoru = shartrig.edit();
       tri.setChecked(shartrig.getBoolean(ex, false));
       tri.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
           @Override
           public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isxChecked) {
               if (isxChecked) {
                   editoru.putBoolean(ex, true);
               } else {
                   editoru.putBoolean(ex, false);
               }
               editoru.commit();
           }
       });


       engl = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch25);
       sharing = getSharedPreferences("engl", MODE_PRIVATE);
       final SharedPreferences.Editor editort = sharing.edit();
       engl.setChecked(sharing.getBoolean(ex, false));
       engl.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
           @Override
           public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean iseChecked) {
               if (iseChecked) {
                   editort.putBoolean(ex, true);
               } else {
                   editort.putBoolean(ex, false);
               }
               editort.commit();
           }
       });

       inf = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch19);
       sharinf = getSharedPreferences("inf", MODE_PRIVATE);
       final SharedPreferences.Editor editorc = sharinf.edit();
       inf.setChecked(sharinf.getBoolean(ex, false));
       inf.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
           @Override
           public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isinChecked) {
               if (isinChecked) {
                   editorc.putBoolean(ex, true);
               } else {
                   editorc.putBoolean(ex, false);
               }
               editorc.commit();
           }
       });

       edf = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch11);
       sharedf = getSharedPreferences("edf", MODE_PRIVATE);
       final SharedPreferences.Editor editoredf = sharedf.edit();
       edf.setChecked(sharedf.getBoolean(ex, false));
       edf.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
           @Override
           public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isedfChecked) {
               if (isedfChecked) {
                   editoredf.putBoolean(ex, true);
               } else {
                   editoredf.putBoolean(ex, false);
               }
               editoredf.commit();
           }
       });

       reli = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch26);
       sharrel = getSharedPreferences("reli", MODE_PRIVATE);
       final SharedPreferences.Editor editorrel = sharrel.edit();
       reli.setChecked(sharrel.getBoolean(ex, false));
       reli.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
           @Override
           public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isrelChecked) {
               if (isrelChecked) {
                   editorrel.putBoolean(ex, true);
               } else {
                   editorrel.putBoolean(ex, false);
               }
               editorrel.commit();
           }
       });

       est = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch23);
       sharest = getSharedPreferences("est", MODE_PRIVATE);
       final SharedPreferences.Editor editorest = sharest.edit();
       est.setChecked(sharest.getBoolean(ex, false));
       est.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
           @Override
           public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isestChecked) {
               if (isestChecked) {
                   editorest.putBoolean(ex, true);
               } else {
                   editorest.putBoolean(ex, false);
               }
               editorest.commit();
           }
       });

       pol = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch18);
       sharpol = getSharedPreferences("pol", MODE_PRIVATE);
       final SharedPreferences.Editor editorpol = sharpol.edit();
       pol.setChecked(sharpol.getBoolean(ex, false));
       pol.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
           @Override
           public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean ispolChecked) {
               if (ispolChecked) {
                   editorpol.putBoolean(ex, true);
               } else {
                   editorpol.putBoolean(ex, false);
               }
               editorpol.commit();
           }
       });

       eti = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch20);
       shareti = getSharedPreferences("eti", MODE_PRIVATE);
       final SharedPreferences.Editor editoreti = shareti.edit();
       eti.setChecked(shareti.getBoolean(ex, false));
       eti.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
           @Override
           public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isetiChecked) {
               if (isetiChecked) {
                   editoreti.putBoolean(ex, true);
               } else {
                   editoreti.putBoolean(ex, false);
               }
               editoreti.commit();
           }
       });
       mate = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch17);
       sharemate = getSharedPreferences("mate", MODE_PRIVATE);
       final SharedPreferences.Editor editormate = sharemate.edit();
       mate.setChecked(sharemate.getBoolean(ex, false));
       mate.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
           @Override
           public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean ismateChecked) {
               if (ismateChecked) {
                   editormate.putBoolean(ex1, true);
               } else {
                   editormate.putBoolean(ex1, false);
               }
               editormate.commit();
           }
       });

       tvBoton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Horario);
       tvBoton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                   Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, xyz.devleen.administradordetareas1.orario.class);
                   startActivity(i);
               }
           });
   }
}
```

Comment: Si lees el error te está diciendo exactamente qué falla....: `Binary XML file line #281: You must supply a layout_width attribute` Es decir, no has puesto `layout_width` al xml del layout de tu segunda activity. Te recomiendo *encarecidamente* leer las trazas de error con cuidado y no asustarte al verlos... pues por regla general suelen indicar con bastante exactitud cual es el problema!

Answer (score 0):

Revisa el error:

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #281
> in xyz.devleen.administradordetareas1:layout/main_activity: Binary XML
> file line #281: You must supply a layout_width attribute.

En tu archivo `main_activity.xml` no estas definendo el atributo `layout_width`, definelo como:

```
layout_width="match_parent"
```